# SQL Server Join all Records without Dups

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2016, I can't seem to figure this out.  I have two tables, TableA and TableB:

```
TableA
Item|  Value   |   ValueID
--------------------------
1   |  AAA     |    1
1   |  BBB     |    2


TableB
Item|  Value   |   ValueID
--------------------------
1   |  XXX     |    1
1   |  YYY     |    2
1   |  ZZZ     |    3


What I want to output is:

Item |  ValueA  |  ValueIDA | ValueB  |  ValueIDB
--------------------------------------------------
1    |  AAA     |   1        |  XXX    |  1
1    |  BBB     |   2        |  YYY    |  2
1    | [NULL]   |  [NULL]    |  ZZZ    |  3
```

I've tried every combination of JOIN I can think of, but I am unable to get this result.

Thanks in advance
-MH

Comment: You can do TableA right join TableB on ValueID

Comment: I think you want a full outer join with aliases on value ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `left join` or `full outer join`.  In this case:

```
select b.item, a.value as valuea, a.valueid as valueida,
       b.value as valueb, b.valueid as valueidb
from b left join
     a
     on b.item = a.item and b.valueid = a.valueid;
```

If you could have rows in `a` that you want to keep even with no matches in `b`, then use `full join`.  In that case, you'll want to use `coalesce(a.item, b.item) as item` in the `select`.

Comment: Ok - I see my problem  This was actually the query (along with FULL OUTER JOIN) that I was trying.  My problem was I was also predicating on the Item column (which i did not include in my question).  I was only predicating on one of the tables:

WHERE a.Item = 1

It should be WHERE a.Item = 1 or b.Item = 1

Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Use `RIGHT JOIN`

```
SELECT TableB.ItemID ,
       TableA.Value AS ValueA ,
       TableA.ValueID AS ValueIDA ,
       TableB.Value AS ValueB ,
       TableB.ValueID AS ValueIDB
FROM   TABLEA
       RIGHT JOIN TableB ON TableA.ValueID = TableB.ValueID;
```